# React Different Headers On Different Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i want to make a different **header & footer** inside the dashboard but it still not working , how to make it work it only works inside the router itself only

here is my code :

```
 <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" >
        <Header /> 
        <Route index element={<><Hero /><HomeAbout /> <Slider /> </>} />
        <Route exact path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route exact path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/dashboard">
        <HeaderDashBoard/>
        <Route index  />
      </Route>


    </Routes>
      <Footer /> 
 </Router>
```

also is this the right format to make a dashboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use nested routes in this case

Make another component to serve as a template

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const HomeTemplate = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header /> 
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
```

And now nest your routes like so

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="" element={<HomeTemplate />}>
        <Route index element={<><Hero /><HomeAbout /> <Slider /> </>} </Route>
        <Route exact path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route exact path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>
 </Routes>
```

Now all the routes will be wrapped with the Home Template and all the elements will be rendered where the Outlet is in the Home Template

Comment: thank you so much its working , didn't know about Outlet its so useful :)